# Can't find 'secure_file_priv' variable in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, configuration, permissions

I'm using mysql, and I want to enable saving queries to text files in any location. Currently, when I run the mysql command:

```
show variables like 'secure_file_priv';
```

I receive the value for 'secure_file_priv':

```
/var/lib/mysql-files/
```

I am able to save my queries to files in this location but nowhere else of course. (I'm also having trouble accessing this folder, even when I try to access it as root)

I found my 'my.cnf' file in '/etc/my.cnf', but it doesn't contain the variable 'secure_file_priv'!

I added it in myself as:

```
secure_file_priv=""
```

But this didn't do anything.

I also tried changing it through the mysql terminal, but it is a readonly variable, so I wasn't able to.

Where is this variable located and how can I change it to allow me to write the results of queries to files anywhere?

Comment: Did you restart the service after changing /etc/my.cnf?

Comment: yes, I restarted it